# Compare current time (hours) with time range in Transaction SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to capture the time of a file drop in an automation in SFMC in hours. So, I think I will have to capture time stamp as now() in hours.

Then I have to compare the current hour to a time range, e.g. between 7pm and 10pm (19:00 and 22:00).

If the current time is within the time window create a record in a DE, if not create 2 records or overwrite the DE with 0 records.

Any ideas how I can do it with a query with 2005 transnational SQL in SFMC? The queries need to be in a syntax similar to Ms SQL Server 2005 that works with Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "transaction SQL" or MySQL?  The former is associated with SQL Server.

Comment: transnational SQL. SFMC uses 2005 SQL version. Thank you